# CouchDB Storing Credentials on the Client Side

Tags: javascript, angularjs, security, couchdb, pouchdb

I'm trying to make a mobile application with Cordova, AngularJS, and a PouchDB/CouchDB backend.  Right now as a test case, I'm using the initial admin account of CouchDB for all connections.  I know CouchDB has options to create a new user with limited capabilities.  However, it still seems like a huge security flaw to store the credentials for that user type on the client side.

Are there any alternatives if I don't necessarily want the user to provide the credentials himself and I don't want the credentials to be in plain text on the client javascript code?

Comment: you can put a server in front of couch, say php or node to relay data while keeping secrets.

Comment: I thought about that, but then I can no longer use the capabilities of PouchDB (to build an "offline" app for example) to sync up to the CouchDB server.  Writing the sync code myself on a php or node server seems like a huge undertaking

Comment: you don't have to re-invent each call, you could make a parasitic request modifier that alters the request a little bit, like substituting the credentials on any request, passing the rest un-altered; could be done in a few lines and would give you a very flexible validation opportunity, at the cost of extended ping times...

Answer (score 3):

You definitely should not give admin rights on the client side, but CouchDB allows any new user to just sign up, so why not use that?

Also for the record, I documented just about everything I know about the CouchDB authentication system here; you might find it useful: https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-authentication/blob/master/README.md#couchdb-authentication-recipes